# Cannot map data coming from backend to frontend react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: companyDetails.map is not a function

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Company = () => {
  const [companyDetails, setCompanyDetails] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  function getData() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.text();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setCompanyDetails(data);
      });
  }

  if (companyDetails.length > 0) {
    return companyDetails.map((data) => {
      return (
        <div key={data.id}>
          <p>{data.company_name}</p>
          <p>{data.cin}</p>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

export default Company;
```

I am learning React, but I am not able to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Are you learning react, or JS? .map is an array method. Probably your companyDetails is not an array. put some console logs to see what it is.

Comment: You `return response.text()`, which means `data` (in the next `then` callback) will be a string. While strings are technically arrays of UTF16 code points, you have to coerce them into an array to make that happen. I expect you meant to use `return response.json()` instead, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting MDN: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text)

> The text() method of the Response interface takes a ***Response*** stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with a ***String***. The response is always decoded using UTF-8.

So you're not getting an array, you're getting a string.

You're probably looking for the "resp.json()" method, which parses your response into valid JSON.

You can try this:

```
function getData() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json(); // <- This is what you need to change
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setCompanyDetails(data);
      });
  }
```